# How to fill a part of a multidimensional array in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am facing a problem in trying to fill a multidimensional array m[4][4][3][3]. 
These are actually 16 3x3 matrices that I already know, which I am trying to fill. What is the correct way to do this? I am getting an error :"16: expected primary-expression before '{' token"

Please help.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int m[4][4][3][3];//0,1,2,3 HLUT

    m[0][0]={1,0,1,
             1,1,1,
             1,0,1};
    m[0][1]={1,1,1,
             0,1,0,
             1,1,1};
    m[0][2]={1,0,1,
             1,1,1,
             1,0,1};
    m[0][3]={1,1,1,
             0,1,0,
             1,1,1};


    m[1][0]={1,0,0,
             1,0,0,
             1,1,1};
    m[1][1]={0,0,1,
             0,0,1,
             1,1,1};
    m[1][2]={1,1,1,
             0,0,1,
             0,0,1};
    m[1][3]={1,1,1,
             1,0,0,
             1,0,0};


    m[2][0]={1,0,1,
             1,0,1,
             1,1,1};
    m[2][1]={1,1,1,
             0,0,1,
             1,1,1};
    m[2][2]={1,1,1,
             1,0,1,
             1,0,1};
    m[2][3]={1,1,1,
             1,0,0,
             1,1,1};


    m[3][0]={1,1,1,
             0,1,0,
             0,1,0};
    m[3][1]={1,0,0,
             1,1,1,
             1,0,0};
    m[3][2]={0,1,0,
             0,1,0,
             1,1,1};
    m[3][3]={0,0,1,
             1,1,1,
             0,0,1};

}
```

Comment: Visual Studio gives a better error message: `error C3863: array type 'int [3][3]' is not assignable`

Comment: Why is it not assignable? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I've never tried to do it before, but I don't think it's possible. I can't say for sure, though.

Comment: Doesn't that try to assign 9 elements to an array with 3 spaces?  I think you need to do `m[0][0][0] = {1,1,1};` and so on.  You can also try using double braces with `m[0][0] = {{1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1}};`.  I'm not near my compiler so I can't test it...

Comment: See this post: [How to declare and initialize in a 4-dimensional array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863417/how-to-declare-and-initialize-in-a-4-dimensional-array-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't initialize a multidimensional array like that. If you want to do so do it like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int m[4][4][3][3] = {1,0,1, //1
             1,1,1,
             1,0,1,

             1,1,1,     //2
             0,1,0,
             1,1,1,

             1,0,1,     //3
             1,1,1,
             1,0,1,

            // ...
            // ...

             1,0,1,     //16
             1,1,1,
             1,0,1};


    for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
        for(int j=0;j<4;++j) {
            for(int p=0;p<3;++p) {
                for(int q=0;q<3;++q)
                    std::cout<<m[i][j][p][q];
                std::cout<<std::endl;
            }
            std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
}
```

Or else use 4 `for` loops to assign your array. You must always remember that a multidimensional array is nothing but a single dimensional array in memory, so initialize it like a single dimensional only.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the correct way to do this?

You can use one of the following options:

1. You can initialize all the elements of the matrix at initialization time.
2. Initialize the members to `0`. Then set the values of the elements one by one.
3. Use `std::vector` instead of plain old arrays.
4. Use `std::array` instead of plain old arrays.

**Method 1: Initialize all elements**

```
int main()
{

   int m[4][4][3][3] =
   {
      1,0,1,
      1,1,1,
      1,0,1,

      1,1,1,
      0,1,0,
      1,1,1,

      1,0,1,
      1,1,1,
      1,0,1,

      1,1,1,
      0,1,0,
      1,1,1,

      1,0,0,
      1,0,0,
      1,1,1,

      0,0,1,
      0,0,1,
      1,1,1,

      1,1,1,
      0,0,1,
      0,0,1,

      1,1,1,
      1,0,0,
      1,0,0,

      1,0,1,
      1,0,1,
      1,1,1,

      1,1,1,
      0,0,1,
      1,1,1,

      1,1,1,
      1,0,1,
      1,0,1,

      1,1,1,
      1,0,0,
      1,1,1,

      1,1,1,
      0,1,0,
      0,1,0,

      1,0,0,
      1,1,1,
      1,0,0,

      0,1,0,
      0,1,0,
      1,1,1,

      0,0,1,
      1,1,1,
      0,0,1
   };

}
```

**Method 2: Assign to individual elements**

```
int main()
{

   int m[4][4][3][3] = {};

   m[0][0][0][0] = 1;
   m[0][0][0][1] = 0;
   m[0][0][0][2] = 1;

   ...

   m[3][3][2][0] = 0;
   m[3][3][2][1] = 0;
   m[3][3][2][2] = 1;

}
```

**Method 3: Use `std::vector`**

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> m1(3);
   std::vector<decltype(m1)> m2(3, m1);
   std::vector<decltype(m2)> m3(4, m2);
   std::vector<decltype(m3)> m(4, m3);

   m[0][0][0] = {1, 0, 1};
   m[0][0][1] = {1, 1, 1};
   m[0][0][2] = {1, 0, 1};

   ...

   m[3][3][0] = {0, 0, 1};
   m[3][3][1] = {1, 1, 1};
   m[3][3][2] = {0, 0, 1};

   return 0;
}
```

**Method 4: Use `std::array`**

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
   std::array<int, 3> m1;
   std::array<decltype(m1), 3> m2;
   std::array<decltype(m2), 4> m3;
   std::array<decltype(m3), 4> m;

   m[0][0][0] = {1, 0, 1};
   m[0][0][1] = {1, 1, 1};
   m[0][0][2] = {1, 0, 1};

   ...

   m[3][3][0] = {0, 0, 1};
   m[3][3][1] = {1, 1, 1};
   m[3][3][2] = {0, 0, 1};

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m[0][0]={1,0,1,
         1,1,1,
         1,0,1};
```

is effectively attempting to assign a single dimensional array of 9 `int`s to a  a 2-dimensional array of 3 `int`s.

Change your initial declaration to

```
int m[4][4][9]
```

Comment: The problem still persists.
The error message is still: 16: expected primary-expression before '{' token

Comment: That is incorrect. You cannot assign an initialization list to an element of an array even if that element itself is an array.